# How to set Tab bar item badgeValue in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Actually I have one custom `TabBarController` and I need to set badgeValue for separate `tabbaritem` at initially that custom tabar loaded with that index path of the tab bar item.

```
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"3";
```

I used above code for that `UIViewcontroller` but it shows only when I click on the tab bar item.

and I have also tried the below code in `custom tabBarController` but it didn't working.

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:@"2"];
```

I need to display the badge value at initial.

Comment: what do you mean by initial ? mean when your tabbarcontroller load and show first tab ?

Comment: yeah the first tab....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set badge number when you show first tab of your `tabbarcontroller` then set

```
  [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:@"2"];
```

in `viewdidload` of your first tab, means first `viewcontroller` of your `tabbbarcontroller`

Comment: can i declare it in didReceiveRemoteNotification method on appdelegate.m

Comment: yes you can but for that you have to instantiate `tabbarcontroller` by setting `storyboard id` to your `tabbarcontroller` because you can not get `self.tabBarController` in appdelegate!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `AppDelegate` where you are setting TabBarController as root view controller of `UIWindow` like this.

```
[self.windows setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

Just write this code before setting the root view controller and after initialising the tabBarController object completely.

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:@"2"];
```